# Programmatically running EMF code generation

Tags: eclipse-emf

I have created an EMF model with extension `.system` which will generate the code for my work.

Now I can generate code using launch code generation action from Eclipse. But I want to generate the code by launching the code generation from a stand-alone program.

How do I achieve this?

Details: I have created a plugin from EMF model and have inlcluded in the Eclipse.

I will created `.system` files from out of my plugin and I can generate code from my plugins.

I have observed that when I click launch the code generation it is starting a `LauchAction` class from my plugin.

How do I start my `LaunchAction` class from a stand-alone Java program?

My aim is to run my created `.system` model and generate the code from a stand-alone Java program.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You might consider refactoring this question. 1.  Turn it into a question.  2.  What is the exact step you are missing?  Example: What snip of code and configuration do I need to make an EMF model into Java Stubs.  3.  Proof read.  I typically can help in this space.  You might message me through this site if you still need help and you update the question.

Answer (score 4):

You could call Eclipse from the command line. Something similar to this:

```
eclipse.exe -noSplash -data ${workspace_location} -model -edit -editor -tests -application org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.Generator ${genmodel}
```

This command will start Eclipse silently and will generate mode code (`-model`), edit plug-in (`-edit`), editor plug-in (`-editor`), and the test plug-in (`-tests`). Leave out any of these parameters if they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to solve your problem, but I think it is doable. I think you have to look at the EMF source code to check how the code generation works.

Here are some starting points:

- If you have PDE and the EMF tools, use use *Import > Plug-ins and Fragments* to get the EMF plugin into your Eclipse workspace.
- Otherwise, clone and import the following Git repository:

  ```
  https://git.eclipse.org/c/emf/org.eclipse.emf.git/
  ```
- Have a look at the following file, maybe you can find what you need there:

  ```
  plugins/org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.ui/src/org/eclipse/emf/codegen/ecore/genmodel/handler/GenerateHandler.java
  ```
- Otherwise, look in the `org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore` plugin.

Good luck! It's an interesting problem! Please report back here if you solve it!

**EDIT:** Ops, this question is 10 years old, I didn't notice!